# How can I not remove the last item in a table?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a table which must have minimum one item. How can I prevent to remove the last item?

For example, I have a table named USER, this table must contain at least one user. I can delete a user, but I cannot delete when the number of users is equal to one.

Comment: Please give more details about what you're trying to accomplish.  It's not clear.

Comment: I edited with one example

Comment: you may right a stored procedure and check if records count(*) > 0 then delete otherwise skip.

Comment: Do you mean you want to stop the last record from being deleted using mysql workbench?  Or do you have an application that you want to prevent the user from deleting the last entry?

Comment: I can do that from my application side, but I think this will not be a good idea. Then I want to do that in the database, directly in phpmyadmin. I can use triggers? Are this the same as stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

you may need to write sp like this.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `deleteuser`(userId INT)
BEGIN
      IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM USER WHERE Id<>userId) THEN

            DELETE FROM USER WHERE Id=userId;   
      END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and you can call it.

```
call deleteuser(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
DELETE FROM USER
WHERE ID = @ID
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER AS t1) > 0
```

Comment: mysql won't allow you to this by saying "You can't specify target table 'user' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: I've edited my answer and added an alias to the table in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TRIGGERS Which will validate the number of rows before Delete query on that table.